# Add Availability zones to VM's

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I imported resources to Azure, mainly virtual machines that work in production, they have DNS. Now, when I want to add availitby zones, it shows me in the plan that it will destroy machines and add new ones. Unfortunately, I don't like this very much because I can't allow the machine to be removed. Can it be done this way?

Edit:

```
    terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.73.0"
    }
  }

  backend "azurerm" {
  }
}

locals {
  team_name       = "RebootRebels"
  environment     = "dev"
  organization    = "pracuj"
  subscription_id = 
  tenant_id       = 
  location        = "northeurope"
  project_name    = "addns"

  virtual_machines = {
    "ns1-vm-eun-dev" = {
      name_vm            = "ns1-vm-${module.azure_general.location_alias}-${local.environment}"
      name_nic           = "ns1-nic-${module.azure_general.location_alias}-${local.environment}"
      admin_username     = "login"
      private_ip_address = "10.252.10.4"
      availability_zones = ["1", "2", "3"]
    }
    "ns2-vm-eun-dev" = {
      name_vm            = "ns2-vm-${module.azure_general.location_alias}-${local.environment}"
      name_nic           = "ns2-nic-${module.azure_general.location_alias}-${local.environment}"
      admin_username     = "login"
      private_ip_address = "10.252.10.5"
      availability_zones = ["1", "2", "3"]
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = local.subscription_id
  tenant_id       = local.tenant_id
  use_cli         = true

  features {}
}

module "azure_general" {
  source          = "../../../../../modules/azure_general"
  environment     = local.environment
  organization    = local.organization
  subscription_id = local.subscription_id
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "${local.project_name}-rg-${module.azure_general.location_alias}-${local.environment}"
  location = local.location
  tags = {
    availability = "24x7"
    environment  = local.environment
    persistent   = "true"
    projectName  = "NameServers for DEV"
    serviceType  = "IaaS"
    teamName     = local.team_name
    tier         = "backEnd"
    type         = "coreInfrastructure"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "nsg" {
  name                = "ns-nsg-${module.azure_general.location_alias}-${local.environment}"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  tags = {
    environment  = local.environment
    persistent   = "true"
    projectName  = "NameServers for DEV"
    serviceType  = "IaaS"
    teamName     = local.team_name
    tier         = "backEnd"
    type         = "coreInfrastructure"
  }
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  name                 = "addns-subnet-${module.azure_general.location_alias}-${local.environment}"
  virtual_network_name = "network-vnet-${module.azure_general.location_alias}-${local.environment}"
  resource_group_name  = "network-rg-${module.azure_general.location_alias}-${local.environment}"
}

data "azurerm_key_vault" "key_vault" {
  name                = "topsecret-vault-eun-dev"
  resource_group_name = "topsecretvault-rg-eun-dev"
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "key_vault_secret" {
  name         = "vm-dns-eun-dev-password"
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.id
}


resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "vm_dns" {

  for_each              = { for index, vm in local.virtual_machines : vm.name_vm => vm }
  name                  = each.value.name_vm
  admin_username        = each.value.admin_username
  admin_password        = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.key_vault_secret.value
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.nic["${local.virtual_machines[each.key].name_nic}"].id]
  zone                  = join(",", each.value.availability_zones)



  size                       = "Standard_B1ms"
  encryption_at_host_enabled = false
  secure_boot_enabled        = false
  timezone                   = "Central European Standard Time"
  vtpm_enabled               = false


  tags = {
    availability = "24x7"
    persistent   = "true"
    projectName  = "NameServers for DEV"
    serviceType  = "IaaS"
    teamName     = local.team_name
    tier         = "backEnd"
    type         = "coreInfrastructure"
  }

  computer_name = each.value.name_vm

  os_disk {
    name                 = "${each.value.name_vm}_OsDisk"
    disk_size_gb         = 127
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    offer     = "WindowsServer"
    sku       = "2019-Datacenter"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      identity
    ]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic" {
  for_each = { for index, vm in local.virtual_machines : vm.name_nic => vm }

  name                = each.value.name_nic
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  tags = {
    availability = "24x7"
    projectName  = "NameServers for DEV"
    serviceType  = "IaaS"
    teamName     = local.team_name
    tier         = "backEnd"
    type         = "coreInfrastructure"
  }

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "ipconfig1"
    subnet_id                     = data.azurerm_subnet.subnet.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Static"
    private_ip_address            = each.value.private_ip_address
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storage_nsdiageundev" {
  name                             = "nsdiag${module.azure_general.location_alias}${local.environment}"
  location                         = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name              = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  account_tier                     = "Standard"
  account_replication_type         = "LRS"
  account_kind                     = "Storage"
  enable_https_traffic_only        = false    #tfsec:ignore:azure-storage-enforce-https
  min_tls_version                  = "TLS1_0" #tfsec:ignore:azure-storage-use-secure-tls-policy
  cross_tenant_replication_enabled = false
}

resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "log_analitycs_dns" {
  name                = "dns-workspace-${module.azure_general.location_alias}-${local.environment}"
  location            = "westeurope"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  sku                 = "Free"
  retention_in_days   = 7
  daily_quota_gb      = 0.5
  tags                = {}
}
```

Comment: Please add any relevant code to the question.

Comment: @MarkoE added code

Comment: Would you mind adding the output with the unwanted behaviour as well?

Comment: When you want to add availability zones to existing virtual machines (VMs) in Azure using Terraform, there are some important considerations to keep in mind. Azure Virtual Machines are assigned to an availability set at the time of creation, and changing their availability zone or availability set involves re-creating the VM. This is why you are seeing a plan to destroy and recreate the VMs when you add availability zones.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to add Available zones to VMs under some special conditions.

In the `azurerm_windows_virtual_machine` resource, you're setting the `zone` attribute using `join(",", each.value.availability_zones)`. The `zone` attribute in this resource expects a single string, not a list. This may be why Terraform is indicating that it will recreate the VMs. Instead of joining the availability zones, you should pick one zone for each VM if you want to distribute them across zones

Adding availability zones to existing VMs will result in VM re-creation. This is by design in Azure; a VM cannot be moved into or out of an availability zone without being recreated.

**My Recommendations on this as an input before provisioning the configuration mentioned is**

1. If you don't want to recreate the VMs, consider not adding availability zones to the existing VMs. Instead, only use availability zones for new VMs you're provisioning.
2. To properly set availability zones, you'd typically set the `zones` attribute as a list and not a single string. Use `zones = each.value.availability_zones` instead of `zone`.
3. Ensure your subnet (`data.azurerm_subnet.subnet`) and network (`data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet`) exist. If they don't, you'll get errors when planning or applying the Terraform code.

**My demo terraform configuration for this:**

```
resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "vm_dns" {
  for_each              = var.virtual_machines
  name                  = each.value.name_vm
  admin_username        = each.value.admin_username
  admin_password        = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.key_vault_secret.value
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.nic[each.key].id]
  zone                  = join(",", each.value.availability_zones)
  size                  = "Standard_B1ms"
  encryption_at_host_enabled = false
  secure_boot_enabled        = false
  timezone                   = "Central European Standard Time"
  vtpm_enabled               = false

  tags = {
    availability = "24x7"
    persistent   = "true"
    projectName  = "NameServers for DEV"
    serviceType  = "IaaS"
    teamName     = var.team_name
    tier         = "backEnd"
    type         = "coreInfrastructure"
  }

  computer_name = each.value.name_vm

  os_disk {
    name                 = "${each.value.name_vm}_OsDisk"
    disk_size_gb         = 127
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    offer     = "WindowsServer"
    sku       = "2019-Datacenter"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      identity
    ]
  }
}
```

**variable file for the respective:**

```
variable "virtual_machines" {
  description = "Map of virtual machine configurations"
  type        = map(object({
    name_vm            = string
    name_nic           = string
    admin_username     = string
    private_ip_address = string
    availability_zones = list(string)
  }))
  default = {
    "ns1-vm-eun-dev" = {
      name_vm            = "ns1-vm-eun-dev"
      name_nic           = "ns1-nic-eun-dev"
      admin_username     = "login"
      private_ip_address = "10.252.10.4"
      availability_zones = ["1", "2", "3"]
    },
    "ns2-vm-eun-dev" = {
      name_vm            = "ns2-vm-eun-dev"
      name_nic           = "ns2-nic-eun-dev"
      admin_username     = "login"
      private_ip_address = "10.252.10.5"
      availability_zones = ["1", "2", "3"]
    }
  }
}

variable "team_name" {
  description = "Name of the team"
  type        = string
  default     = "RebootRebels"
}
```

once you make the necessary changes as per the requirement.

run the commands

**terraform init**

**terraform apply**

with this, we can change the availability zone of the VM with a decent amount of downtime.